# jquery 3.5.1 mobile css formating not showing in live server preview with vs code

Tags: html, jquery, css, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the jquery css stylesheet, but I can't seem to get it to format anything at all. I'm using the live preview extension in VSCode, and the css is from the jquery website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Physics Simulator App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="scripts\jquery-3.5.1.min.js">  </script>
    <script src="scripts\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">  </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts\Week 2 homework.js'>  </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="week 1 homework.html"> Information</a> </li>
                <li><a href="Week 2 App.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"> Interface</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="header">Binary Operators Demo</div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="input">A</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="inputA" id="inputA">
            <br />
            <label for="input">B</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="inputB" id="inputB">
            <br />
            <button onclick="AND();">AND</button>
            <button onclick="OR();">OR</button>
            <button onclick="NOT();">NOT</button>
            <button onclick="XOR();">XOR</button>
        </div>
        <table id="data">
            <tr>
                <td>Result: </td>
                <td id="resultA"></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <small>binary operations demo app</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't think I'm missing anything in terms of brackets, and the file paths work for my own css files. I've tried adding 'data-theme="a"' to my page bracket, but nada. I just get this.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy3xJ.png)

Is it a version issue or?

Comment: Hi, please fix this line `    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts\Week 2 homework.js'>  </script>
` rename your file into a valid name such as `Week2-homework.js`, use your DevTool and check if the css file was well imported to the page.

Comment: @MomoSetti that script works, and it's linked in VSCode. What do you mean "well imported"? VSCode seems to link the css fine.

Comment: i mean check the browser if it loads your CSS file or no, if yes, then your have problem with your html code, go check the documentation of how to use the library, if the browser doesn't load your CSS, go check your CSS file path.

Comment: @MomoSetti I cleaned up the file names and I switched to using the cdn for jquery using 


`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Friend, I may have misunderstood you for not mastering English very well. But as I understand it, your problem is with jquery.mobile.css?
Try  using the CDN. I copied your code and replaced the  with the CDN (I didn't find this Week 2 homework.js).
Replace the  with the CDN and do this test:
Insert this code block:

```
        <div class = "ui-grid-d">
            <div class = "ui-block-a">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow"> button </a> <br>
                <span> any info </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It uses the style of jquery.mobile.css, if it works the problem could be in your import of the files.
Two tips, avoid spaces in the file names, (Week 2, it could be Week_2_homework), and in the `<label for = "">` do not point "`input`", point the **name** you gave to the `input` or the **id**.
If I was wrong about your problem, answer that I try to help you.
Reggards

Comment: Thank you for your response! What should the button look like? I get a blue border button with a white fill and the word "button" in blue.

Comment: Hi, you can add ui-btn-a(or b) in attibute of button. Follow this:
           

`<div class="ui-grid-solo">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow">botao</a><br>
                <span>any info</span>
            </div>
        </div>`


For more informations about jquery mobile read this article http://www.w3big.com/pt/jquerymobile/jquerymobile-themes.html